# Download file and save to disc not working

Tags: java, android, download

I need to dowload file from server, so I'm using retrofit and this method to save file to disc.

Here is my code

```
    @GET
    Call<ResponseBody> downloadFileWithDynamicUrlSync(@Url String fileUrl);
```

Method for dowload file

```
 private void dowloadFile(String url, FileListItem item) {

        Call<ResponseBody> callb = RestClient.getInstance().getService().downloadFileWithDynamicUrlSync(url);

        callb.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "server contacted and has file");
                    boolean writtenToDisk = writeResponseBodyToDisk(response.body(), item);
                    if(writtenToDisk){
                        MdocUtil.showToastShort(context, context.getString(R.string.file_dowloaded_succ));
                    }else{
                        MdocUtil.showToastShort(context, context.getString(R.string.error_download));
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "file download was a success? " + writtenToDisk);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "server contact failed");
                    APIError error = ErrorUtils.parseError(response);
                    MdocUtil.showToastShort(context, error.getMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "error");
            }
        });
    }
```

Method for writing file to disc

```
 private boolean writeResponseBodyToDisk(ResponseBody body, FileListItem item) {
        try {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + File.separator + item.getName());

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream outputStream = null;

            try {
                byte[] fileReader = new byte[4096];

                long fileSize = body.contentLength();
                long fileSizeDownloaded = 0;

                inputStream = body.byteStream();
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                while (true) {
                    int read = inputStream.read(fileReader);

                    if (read == -1) {
                        break;
                    }

                    outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);

                    fileSizeDownloaded += read;

                    Log.d(TAG, "file download: " + fileSizeDownloaded + " of " + fileSize);
                }

                outputStream.flush();

                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }

                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
```

This code works perfectly when dowloding image, but it does not work for .pdf and .docx files, in that case writtenToDisk is true but there is no file on phone.

UPDATE: 
Problem was that I didn't set access token in header, which is requested by server for files but not for images.

Comment: What is the path of the file that you are trying to write to (both in the case of the image, which worked perfectly, and in the case of the other files, that didn't)? And how did you determine that there is no file on the phone?

Comment: Path is same, link from our backend (baseUrl + "v2/common/files/download/" + id) id is also info from backend. I searched my phone for file with name item.getName() - take that value from debug mode but there is no file, I also check My Files app -  Recent files section and Download folder. Forgot to mention that I'm able to download file from iOS app that use same link.

Comment: What is the path of the file that you are trying to **write to** (not the URL you're trying to download from)? How did you search your phone for the file? There are ways to search that won't find all files in every location.

Comment: Found solution, problem was that I didn't set access token in headers, server allowed download for pictures without access token but not for files. So I switched to DownloadManager and add headers.. Now it works..

Comment: Apparently `response.isSuccessful()` returned true, which means the server is returning a `code` in the 200..399 range even though the token was missing. Sounds like a bug on the server side to me.

Comment: It is, learned that hard way..

Comment: In that case it's confusing that you accepted an answer about the DownloadManager. Surely when this server bug is the cause of the problem, using the DownloadManager wouldn't solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the native Android download manager instead?
you can [see here](https://github.com/MohamedWael/MoLib/blob/master/molibrary/src/main/java/com/blogspot/mowael/molib/network/DownloadUtil.java) a download manager util which can be used as the below example:

```
downloadManager = new DownloadManager(new DownloadManager.DownloadCompleteListener(){
    @Override
    public void getProgress(double progress, long downloadedBytes, long sizeInBytes){

    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadComplete(Uri fileLocalUri, long downloadedFileId){

    }
});
downloadManager.download(Uri uri, String fileName, String description);
```